# Запрос sql на выборку с подменой значений (Case и Like)

Tags: sql

Всем привет! Помогите решить задачу. Предположим имеется таблица с полями (id/code/name). В поле код содержатся значения соответствующие определенной категории (могут содержаться в тексте, поэтому приходится использовать Like). К примеру ibm25 - самолеты. ibm25-1 - вертолеты. Нужно написать запрос на выборку, в результате которого, эти коды будут представлены в читабельном виде.
Я написал запрос:

```
select distinct a.category, case WHEN a.category like '%25-1%' THEN 'Немодерируемый UGC'
WHEN a.category like '%IAB25%' THEN 'Нестандартный контент'
else 'Категория отсутствует в справочнике'

end AS "1"
from register.creative a
```

Сложность в том, многие коды могут начинаться одинаково. Пробовал искать по конечной части значений, но  `Like WHEN a.category like '%25-1%' THEN 'вертолеты'` здесь мне все равно возвращает значение "самолеты".

Пример таблицы:
[image: Таблица с данными]

| ID | Type | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Картинка | IAB25 |
| 2 | Видео | IAB25 Non-Standard Contenеt |
| 2 | Видео | IAB25-1 |
| 2 | Видео | IAB26-1 Illegal Content |
| 2 | Видео | IAB25-3 |

Таблица соответствия кодов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

| Code | Name |
| --- | --- |
| IAB25 | Нестандартный контент |
| IAB25-1 | Немодерируемый UGC |
| IAB26 | Незаконный контент |
| IAB26-1 | Незаконный контент |
| IAB25-3 | Нецензурный контент |

На выходе хочу получить вместо IAB.. значение которое ему соответствует.
Помогите разобраться. Может у кого есть еще какие либо варианты решения задачи?

Comment: Полный список кодов есть? *Сложность в том, многие коды могут начинаться одинаково.* Это ты сам себе сложности создаёшь. Тестирование надо начинать с наиболее длинных паттернов.

Comment: есть, могу дать часть, остальные по аналогии. IAB15 Наука
IAB15-1 Астрология
IAB15-2 Биология
IAB15-3 Химия
IAB15-4 Геология
IAB15-5 Физика
IAB15-6 Космос
IAB16 Домашние животные
IAB16-1 Аквариумы 
 и т.д.

Comment: Ну так и приведи пример в вопросе-то... лучше сразу CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO исходных данных и требуемый результат для них.

Comment: Я хочу чтоб вместо кода, на выходе были наименования категории.

Comment: Хоти. Но я лично на "как бы сделать типа вот" ничего кроме "вот как-то так" ответить не смогу.

Comment: Я привел пример таблицы и пример кодов. Может сейчас будет более понятно

Comment: Картинками? и Вы предлагаете МНЕ заниматься составлением структуры таблиц и перенабивать вручную данные, чтобы решить ВАШУ проблему? серьёзно?

Comment: Добавил таблицы

Comment: В следующий раз создавайте сразу fiddle (как у меня в ответе в первом блоке кода) и давайте ссылку - это обычно здорово ускоряет получение ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY content.Category ORDER BY LENGTH(categories.code) DESC) rn
    FROM content
    JOIN categories ON LOCATE(categories.code, content.category)
)
SELECT id, type, category, code, name
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0f5bc4d1c74778cd87427bf7cea9150

Comment: Подскажите, а если бы у нас предположим не было таблица соответствия кодов в бд, но мы предположим знаем какое значение какому соответствует. Возможно ли было бы реализовать при таких условиях эту задачу?

Comment: @АлександрСеребряков Запросто. Создаём таблицу, заполняем её значениями, которые мы знаем, и далее см. запрос выше.

Comment: У вас случайно нет телеграмма?

Comment: @АлександрСеребряков Нет. Даже случайно.

Comment: а можете какую нибудь книгу посоветовать по sql или может видео уроки? читал много книг, но там даже нет функции , которые вы использовали. И можете пояснить пожалуйста свой запрос. Не очень въезжаю , хочется понять логику

Comment: @АлександрСеребряков Логику? Сначала CTE (считай, динамический вьюв). В нём к каждой записи добавляется её номер в группе с одинаковыми Category при сортировке по убыванию длины. Таблицы связываются по факту наличия подстроки. Результат работы CTE хорошо виден, если снаружи просто получить все записи - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d70edc9251c2b9339affbbb385e463dc А снаружи просто отбирается первая из записей группы. Что же до книг - то очень неплохо прочитать официальный справочник по синтаксису и встроенным функциям для СУБД.

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: Подскажите , чем можно заменить функцию locate? (postgres)

Comment: @АлександрСеребряков Функция position. Возможно, дополнительно её результат придётся привести к булеву.